# Twilio API in Node throwing error about user agent

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-node

I'm following the NodeJS Twilio SDK docs with the following:

```js
const twilio = require('twilio')

exports.sendActivationCode = async (phone, activationCode) => {
  const accountSID = '<REDACTED>'
  const authToken = '<REDACTED>'
  const client = twilio(accountSID, authToken)
  return await client.messages.create({
    body: `Your activation code is ${activationCode}`,
    from: '+1<REDACTED>',
    to: `+1${phone.toString().replace(/\D/g, '')}`
  })
}
```

I've checked this numerous times to ensure I have a direct match with the docs. When I try to run the code I get `Error: Headers User-Agent forbidden`. The request itself shows the header is going out: `'User-Agent': 'twilio-node/3.45.0 (node.js v10.15.3)'` and the stack output indicates that this is coming from `jsdom` -> `xhr-utils`.

Comment: I have confirmed your code is correct. Are you sending this from a trial or Dev account? There are some restrictions on sending messages from a trial account. The number has to be a confirmed number. If you have an upgraded account this indeed works. I have sent multiple messages with just a copy and past.

Comment: As far as I can tell everything on the account is fine. We have an account that is actively being billed, I have a phone number, and have tried both the account credentials and test credentials to no avail. I can make requests and get the message on my phone through cURL.

Comment: The above code works fine for me as well.

Comment: Where does this code live and where are you calling it from.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me. Just add the following to your `package.json` file.

```
    "jest": {
      "testEnvironment": "node"
    },
```

Found here:
https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/how-to-disable-jsdom-in-jest-make-jest-run-twice-as-fast-a01193f23405

Comment: This saved me an incredible amount of time and should be write large on the twilio web site!!!! I'd give you a thousand points if I could!